# How to select duplicate features in a group in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to select those features which share the same "Stand ID" in a group to dissolve the geometry afterwards in QGIS 3.1. My Attribute table looks like this:

```
Group Stand-ID
1      5 <-- Duplicate
1      6
1      5 <-- Duplicate
1      2
2      8 
2      9
2      5
3      3
3      4
```

How would the corresponding expression look like in QGIS? 
Group by "Group" > select everything which is not unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QGIS ***Dissolve*** algorithm should fix this for you.

1. Start the Dissolve algorithm from the *Processing Toolbox* (or the *Vector-> Geoprocessing Tools* menu).
2. Select your data set as *Input layer*
3. Click on the **...** button to the right of the *Dissolve field(s)* field to open the *Multiple selection* widget.
4. Check/tick **both** *Group* and *Stand-ID* in the *Multiple selection* widget, and then click the *OK* button to close the widget.
5. Click run

In the output layer, features that have the same *Group*, *Stand-ID* combination have been dissolved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my solution is very nifty but you can try the following.

Add a **virtual field** in your table using this expression :

```
if(count("stand_id", "group"||"stand_id")>1,"group"||"stand_id",'0')
```

That should detect any *(group, stand_id)* duplicate among groups.

You should then be able to base your dissolve operation on that virtual field.